# How to programmatically add a guest attendee to GSuite calendar event on Save

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am building a GSuite Calendar extension.

My extension adds custom information to the description of the new event and needs to systematically add the guest email e.g. test@mydomain.com.

The extension has content-script which injects HTML and javascript in Google calendar add event page. This HTML creates a button on the add event page and when user clicks this button then javascript adds custom information to the description.

Here is the HTML to add button in add event page.

```
html() {
  return `<div>
            <strong>
              <a href='#add-description' id="add-description-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'>Add Custom Details</a>
            </strong>
          </div>`;
}
```

Here is the function which injects HTML and javascript in add event page.

```
inject(eventType) {
  const eventDetails = $('#tabEventDetails');
  eventDetails.find('div:first').after(html(eventType));
  // More javascript
}
```

Here is the function which adds custom details to description.

```
addDescription(content) {
  $('[aria-label="Description"]').html(content);
}
```

I am able to inject into the description, but how can I add a guest programmatically without any user intervention?

Is there any way I can add that guest email using javascript? or use a post save tigger if any?

Any pointers?

Comment: And what's wrong with the answer below?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy unfortunately the answer below just doesn't address the question. It creates a meeting programatically. That's what I am trying to do. I want to add that attendee automatically when a user adds a new meeting to his calendar.

Comment: Try to add more information to your question, like code/examples/links to on how to have a simple format of your extension so we'd try playing around with it... etc, if it's worth to bother

Comment: See updated question

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy so no ideas right?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way no, I'm sorry :/ But here's a +1 :-)

Comment: I don't think there is a solution today. thx for contributing

Answer (score 4):

Add to array 'attendees' objects like {'email': 'lpage@example.com'}:

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
    ]
  }
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
  appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
```